# Using a for-loop when my variable is a whole list and not just an interger (python)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I attached my an excerpt of my code here to help me illustrate my question.

**What this code does:** I read in these lists x1 and vx1 from a textfile (each have "Npoints" elements). After that, I operate on each element in each list and in the end I'm left with *new* lists x2,vx2

**What I want this to do:** I want to create some kind of loop where I execute the same operations I did on my original list, x1 and vx2, but on my new list,x2 and vx2. This should create lists x3 and vx3 which I can operate on again... and so on until I get lists xn, vxn.

Also notice, I already have two for-loops going on to operate on the original (I don't know if this complicates things or not).

Hope you guys can help me! I'm *newish* to Python so I really appreciate any advice you can give. Thank you. :)

```
npoints=999
n1= []
mass1 = []
x1= []
vx1= []
fx_list=[]
G=1
dt=.0001

with open('myfile.dat') as f:
     for row in f.readlines():  
        if not row.startswith("#"):
            spaces=row.split('   ')
            n1.append(float(spaces[0]))
            mass1.append(float(spaces[1]))
            x1.append(float(spaces[2]))
            y1.append(float(spaces[3]))
            z1.append(float(spaces[4]))
            vx1.append(float(spaces[5]))
            vy1.append(float(spaces[6]))
            vz1.append(float(spaces[7]))

     for xn in range(0,npoints): 
          for step in range(0,npoints):

               #This is where I first operate on x1,
               fx=((G*mass1[xn]*mass1[step+1]*((x1[step+1]**2.)-(x1[xn]**2.)))/(abs((x1[step+1]**2)-(x1[xn]**2))**2.)**(3./2.))

               #Then put store it in an array
               fx_list.append(fx)

               fxx= np.array_split(fx_list,npoints)

               fxxx_list=[]

               for xn in range(0,npoints):
                    fxxx= np.sum(fxx[xn])

               #and save that in array. Now I have the accelearation on each particle. 
               fxxx_list.append(fxxx)

               #This is where i begin the integration
               #In other words, this is where I redefine the x/vx values
               vx2=[]

               for xn in range(0,npoints):
                    vx11=vx1[xn]+.5*(fxxx_list[xn]+fxxx_list[xn])*dt
                    vx2.append(vx11)

               x2=[]
               for xn in range(0,npoints):
                    x11=(x1[xn]+vx2[xn]*dt)+(.5*fxxx_list[xn]*(dt**2))

                    x2.append(x11)
               print x2 vx2 #and I want to put these value into where x1 is and loop the whole thing again N number of times
```

Comment: Do you need to keep a "history" of the arrays, or can you write over x1 and vx1?  If not, you should be able to do this pretty easily using two dimensional arrays, where each row is the result of the function performed on the previous row.  However, this could get pretty large pretty quickly, so if you need many iterations this might not be an idea solution.

Comment: I can write over x1 and vx1, but I do need many iterations... Like 10,000. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `readlines` here; just `for row in f:` will iterate over the file while reading just one line into memory at a time.

Comment: @Mckenzie If you can write over x1 and vx1, your code can be modified pretty minimally to get your desired result.  At the end of your nested for-loops, simply copy x2 and vx2 into x1 and vx1, and then repeat the process again on the updated x1 and vx1 lists.  This can be done using another loop that wraps around your nested for-loops.

Comment: @acn3 By copying x2 and vx2 into x1 and vx1 do you mean put x2 everywhere x1 is and so on? Then have the for-loop that wraps around the code say like... for x2 in range(0,n)?? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be modified pretty minimally to loop N times and perform the same function on `x1` and `vx1`.  All you need is to wrap your nested for-loop in another loop, and write over `x1` and `vx1` at the end of each iteration.

The basic idea I'm describing is fairly common, and a generic implementation is shown below.  In this case, your `someFunction` would be the entire nested for-loop routine that you perform to create `x2` and `vx2`.

```
x1, vx1 = [], [] # x1 and vx1 are initialized to some values, as you do at the top of your with... as... block

# Loop N times, essentially performing the function on xn, vxn until you arrive at xN, vxN
for n in range(N):
    # Perform some function on x1 and vx1 that results in x2 and vx2
    # This function can be as complex as you need it to be, but if it is complex (as it seems to be), I would recommend moving it to its own function as I show here
    x2, vx2 = someFunction(x1, vx1)

    # Write over x1 and vx1 so they can be used in future iterations of the function
    x1, vx1 = x2, vx2

# x1 and vx1 are not essentially xN and vxN
```

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed works and is really simple. I guess I just didn't understand some of the ways to use for-loops. However, since I need so many iterations, you're right, this method takes too long....  (I ran it all night with the number of iterations I needed and it still didn't finish) so I guess I'll need to find another way. But thank you, this helped!

Comment: @Mckenzie If my answer fully answers your question, you might consider accepting it as the answer to the question to help others and asking another question in a different post.

Answer (score 0):

In this code I end up with an "list-of-lists" which will make a history of the data for every nth iteration that you make. You perform your super long looking function, but for demonstration I just add 1 to every element.

```
x1 = [25, 40, 60, 100, 32, 51]
position_array = []
n_times = 5

position_array.append(x1[:])
for i in range(n_times):
    for j in range(len(x1)):
        x1[j] = x1[j] + 1
    position_array.append(x1[:])

print(position_array)
```

The notation `position_array.append(x1[:])` appends a copy of the nth modified x1 list to the new "list-of-lists". Circumventing a frequent beginner python coder mistake of appending the same outcome list over and over again. So this outputs:

```
[[25, 40, 60, 100, 32, 51], 
[26, 41, 61, 101, 33, 52], 
[27, 42, 62, 102, 34, 53], 
[28, 43, 63, 103, 35, 54], 
[29, 44, 64, 104, 36, 55], 
[30, 45, 65, 105, 37, 56]]
```

If you do not want a history of your nth modifications you can just do this:

```
x1 = [25, 40, 60, 100, 32, 51]
position_array = []
n_times = 5

for i in range(n_times):
    for j in range(len(x1)):
        x1[j] = x1[j] + 1
print(x1)
```

which will simply output:

```
[30, 45, 65, 105, 37, 56]
```